# Is a byte[]'s byte.length() the maximum size or actual size?

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays

I feel like I'm taking 2 steps back with this question, but something is confusing me a little. I'm working with some communication via TCP/IP and byte[]'s.

So I start building my byte[] array, and the third byte requires the length of the byte[]. If I declare my byte like so;

```
byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[119];
```

and then fill in the first three bytes with data..

```
bytesToSend[0] = 0x40;
bytesToSend[1] = 0x40;
bytesToSend[2] = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length.ToString())[0];
```

and finally just print out the third byte, which should contain the length;

```
MessageBox.Show(BitConverter.ToString(bytesToSend));
```

should I be expecting it to return the byte size of 119, or is this just the maximum size? Currently it's returning hex "0x31", which as far as i'm aware doesn't equal 119 or 3. This is no doubt something simple / fundamental I'm missing, but could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why on earth would you placed the length of the `byte[]` within the same `byte[]` that makes no sense.  It should be seperate and/or you should always use the same size array.

Comment: Uh, i need to place the length of the byte within the same byte because that's the protocol for a third party device? I can give you their number if you'd like to ring them and ask?

Comment: @Ramhound Obviously what he needs in the length of the message, not the length of the `byte[]`.

Comment: @Rotem - What is obvious? He says "and the third byte requires the length of the byte[]." which makes no sense. If the third element within the `byte[]` is the length of the `byte[]` then it would be included in the length of the `byte[]` itself.  I gurantee you that the library is expecting the maximum size of the message itself.

Comment: It still doesn't matter as the byte protocol requires it..It's easier to adhere to the protocol, than to get the manufacturer to change their software to just work the length out themselves, flash all the devices and whatnot.

Comment: @Ramhound if this `byte[]` is later sent over TCP/IP or some other 'raw' protocol then the receiving end needs a way of knowing how big the message is so it can know when to stop reading. Some protocols use a delimiter, others encode the length of the message withing the first few bytes.

Comment: @Rotem - I understand that. My point was the author's statement and explaination is confusing.  I am still not convinced he actually got the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems you are unclear on what you are actually doing here:

```
bytesToSend[2] = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length.ToString())[0];
```

Let's break this line down:

```
bytesToSend.Length
```

Returns the integer 119

```
.ToString()
```

Returns the string "119"

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("119")
```

Returns a byte array of the characters that make up the ascii string "119".

```
[0]
```

Get just the first byte of this array, which would equal 0x31, because this is the ascii code for the character '1'.

Also, there is no such thing as an *actual* size of a c# `Array`. There is only a `Length`. If you mean to ask how many of the elements contain non-zero bytes, that's another story, but once you declare

```
byte[] bytesToSend = new byte[119];
```

You get a byte array with 119 elements, and it's `Length` will always be 119, regardless of how many elements you have modified.

If you need to use a collection with a more dynamic size, consider using a `List<byte>` instead.

Comment: aha, i knew when i popped [0] on the end i was doing something wrong. but it took the red squiggly away so i assumed something would come out okay! Note to self; dont do it.

Comment: @Shane Your mistake was converting this value to a string to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the help : ) Still can't help but feel this sounded like a lecture from my father though! aha

Comment: @Shane.C Sorry if it sounds that way, but everyone's a beginner at some point :)

Comment: heyyyyyyyyy wait a minute!

Answer (score 5):

`bytesToSend.Length` will be 119. However, rather than storing `119` in `bytesToSend[2]`, you're

- Converting it to a string, `"119"`
- Converting that string to its ASCII representation in a byte array, `[49, 49, 57]`
- Taking the first byte of that result, `49` or `0x31`.

You just need to do

```
bytesToSend[2] = (byte)bytesToSend.Length;
```

although this will break if you're sending more than 255 bytes,

Answer (score 1):

```
bytesToSend.Length == 119
bytesToSend.Length.ToString() == "119"
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length.ToString()) == {0x31,0x31,0x39}
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length.ToString())[0] == 0x31
```

Comment: I don't see how this code can be maintained in the slightest.  Why do you even convert it to a `string`.  Furthermore there are lots of ways to get a `119` as the Length which would still be correct.  Why exactly do you have a boolean statement within GetBytes?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bytesToSend.Length.ToString())[0];
```

first converts the value "119" (the string value of the array's length) to the byte array {0x31, 0x31, 0x39}, the ascii values for 1, 1, 9.  Then you are taking the first of those and assigning it to bytesToSend[2].  And that is how you are obtaining `0x31`.

So to answer your question, the length of the array is the length that you gave it, i.e. 119 in this case.